# Cannot import Items to Scrapy Spider [No module named] - Python

Tags: python, scrapy

I have troubles importing Items.py from parent folder when using Scrapy framework. I've read that this is a fairly common issue but none of the proposed solution could work for me so far.

I've created a new project via *scrapy startproject ime_projekta*. CMD prompted me with:

```
ime_projekta.spiders.worldmaps
```

The error I am presented is *No module named* as indicated in CMD below. Any help would be great.

Thank you

[image: code]

Comment: As I understood, you want to run `weedMapsSpider`.. right? This can be done by running `scrapy crawl weedMapsSpider` on the cmd

Comment: I am trying to import items.py to the spider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by putting my spider in the same solder as items.py

Answer (score 0):

There is no `__init__.py` file in the `ime_projeckta` folder. Either add one, or switch the line 3 of `worldmaps.py` to a relative import (`from ..items`).

Also note that you are trying to import Item from the wrong import path. It should be `ime_projeckta.items`.

Comment: Could you shed any light how to do relative import of this:
`from ime_projekta.spiders.worldmaps.Items import ImeProjektaItem`

Comment: Added to the response. Also, I believe Python is case-sensitive, so write `items`, not `Items`, to refer to `items.py`.